# Evento al seleccionar un item de un listbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, listbox

Estoy intentado tener el evento al dar click sobre uno de los items de un listbox, he buscado la [documentación](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/listbox-in-C-Sharp/) de [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) pero no se encuentra nada por el estilo

He ensayo los eventos [SelectedIndexChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) y [SelectedIndexChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) pero tampoc han servido ya que no se lanzan cuando selecciono un item, conocen alguna forma de obtener el evento al seleccionar uno de los items

PD:
Mi listBox esta conformado por un objeto en particular y solo se muestra uno de sus atributos.

HelpMe

Comment: No entiendo. `SelectedIndexChanged` se dispara en cuanto seleccionas cualquier item de un listbox. Que problema tienes realmente?

Comment: el evento que mencionas SelectedIndexChanged se dispara cuando vas cambiando la seleccion entre los items de la lista, no entiendo porque dices que no funciona. Estas seguro que asociaste el evento al metodo que defines en el codigo ?

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo de tu evento SelectedIndexChanged ya que este es el evento que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, usa la el evento `Click`, y dentro puedes ponerle algo como esto para recuperar la posición

> suponiendo que tenemos un `listBox` con los datos
>
> 1. Valor1
> 2. Valor2 <- Se clickea este.
> 3. Valor3

```
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)    
    {    
     //El entero que se guardara respetando el caso de arriba es 1.
      int pos_lb1 = listBox1.SelectedIndex; 
    }
```

El condicional que le pongo es para que no traiga el valor `-1` cuando selecciona alguna parte sin item ya que el evento se lanza cada vez que se hace un click dentro del control.

Y este para traer el dato

```
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)    
    {    
     //El string que se guardara en la variable sera "Valor2" respetando el caso del inicio.
      string pos_lb1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.toString(); 
    }
```

Espero que te halla sido util.

Answer (score 0):

En el evento se agrega lo que quieres que haga yo en mi caso mando llamar un sub que realiza la tarea tomando en cuenta el valor del ítem y este se activa cada que cambias de selección.

Private Sub ComboMetodoPago_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboMetodoPago.SelectedIndexChanged
        CARGARPAGO()
    End Sub